# Will killing ArcMap process while it's copying features corrupt the file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase, copy

So..., I made the unfortunate decision to try and copy/paste 22,000+ address points into the same file geodatabase.  It's taking soooooooo long....  So my question is, how much of a chance is there to corrupt a file geodatabase during a copy/paste operation if you kill the ArcMap process midway thru?

Comment: I'm guessing it will not corrupt the geodatabase, however the feature class that the copy is based to maybe compromised (number of features may not equal number of geometric shapes).

Comment: 22k points is not very many. It shouldn't take more than a few minutes to copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult, though possible, to corrupt a file geodatabase.  You should
certainly delete the table that was loading when the application was terminated.

22k points doesn't seem like a lot, so there may be other issues at play here
(and these issues may increase the probability of corruption).

Answer (score 0):

I have check the same with copy/paste (5400 polylignes) and kill application before the end but the process is in transactional mode when you are on edit mode. I haven't data corruption after premature kill process. I think this the transactional mode. I have same number of entities as intial step